# Possible to augment typing for one package from another package?

Tags: typescript

My app is using Chart.PieceLabel.js, which augments Chart.js:

```
npm install chart.js chart.piecelabel.js
```

I am installing types for Chart.js from DefinitelyTyped:

```
npm install @types/chart.js
```

I would like to contribute typings to the Chart.PieceLabel.js repo, but I am not able to get my app to recognize them (it registers the typings for Chart.js, but when I `npm link` or edit types straight in node_modules/chart.piecelabel.js, TypeScript doesn't see my augmentation.

I use Chart.js and Chart.PieceLabel.js in my app like this:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'
import 'chart.piecelabel.js'
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'

let chart = <Doughnut options={{..}} />
```

My typings are in this commit: https://github.com/bcherny/Chart.PieceLabel.js/commit/9e6744c.

And my app code is here: https://git.io/vF23g.

An isolated reproduction case is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/zbj4nf?file=index.ts, and works fine.

Is my tsconfig.json misconfigured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the augmentations to take effect, the module that defines augmentations must be included in the compilation.

If you distributed `Chart.PieceLabel.d.ts` as separate package in @types, it would have been included automatically:

[@types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

But when it's included in its main javascript package in `node_modules`, it must be referenced explicitly somewhere. You can include its `.d.ts` explicitly in `files` section in `tsconfig.json`, or you can just do `import` without importing anything, it's called "[import for side-effects only](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only)".

I just tried to install all necessary typings

```
npm i chart.js chart.piecelabel.js @types/chart.js react-chartjs-2 @types/react
```

applied your changes to `node_modules/chart.piecelabel.js` package

and tried this with typescript 2.6 - it compiles:

```
import 'chart.piecelabel.js'

import * as Chart from 'chart.js';

import * as React from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2'

let o: Chart.ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    pieceLabel: {
        render: 'label'
    }
};


let d = React.createElement(Doughnut, {
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        pieceLabel: {
            render: 'label'
        }
    },
    data: undefined as any // just to make it compile
});
```

**UPDATE**

here are my steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/bayesimpact/tds-frontend.git
cd tds-frontend
git checkout personal/bcherny/publish-types
npm i  
./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

it says "Version 2.6.1"

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

it spits out lots of errors starting with

```
 src/components/LeftPane/Drawers/ServiceAreasDrawer/
      ServiceAreasDrawer.tsx(64,10): error TS2684: The this context of type 
'LoDashExplicitWrapper<[string, string][]>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'LoDashExplicitWrapper<ArrayLike<[string, string]> | Dictionary<[string, string]> | NumericDiction...'.
      Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
          Type '<T>(this: _.LoDashExplicitWrapper<ArrayLike<T> | null | undefined>, ...items: T[]) => _.LoDashExp...' is not assignable to type '<T>(this: _.LoDashExplicitWrapper<ArrayLike<T> | null | undefined>, ...items: T[]) => _.LoDashExp...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
              Type 'LoDashExplicitWrapper<[string, string][]>' is not assignable to type 'LoDashExplicitWrapper<ArrayLike<[string, string]> | Dictionary<[string, string]> | NumericDiction...'. 
src/components/LeftPane/Drawers/ServiceAreasDrawer/ 
    ServiceAreasDrawer.tsx(65,10): error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

When I remove `"strict": true` from `tsconfig.json`, the only remaining errors are:

```
src/services/api.ts(12,11): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ body: string; headers: { Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string; }; method: "GET" | "POST"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][]'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'Accept' does not exist in type 'Headers | string[][]'.
src/services/effects.ts(80,17): error TS2339: Property 'distance_to_closest_provider' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(81,17): error TS2339: Property 'time_to_closest_provider' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(85,19): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(86,42): error TS2339: Property 'distance_to_closest_provider' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(87,38): error TS2339: Property 'time_to_closest_provider' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(88,42): error TS2339: Property 'closest_provider_by_distance' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/services/effects.ts(89,38): error TS2339: Property 'closest_provider_by_time' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I think that the first one is due to the [known recent bug in DOM typings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19656), I have no idea about the others, but I don't see any error related to `pieceLabel` in Doughnut options.

**UPDATE 2**

I just tried different versions of typescript:

```
npm i typescript@2.5
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

no errors

However webpack said:

```
Failed to load ./.env.
```

So maybe you may have something in `.env` file affecting this.

Also - I tried typescript 2.4 - no errors too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this is the issue I'm having. I edited the original question with a code sample - does that help? I believe my issue has to do with not using the correct syntax to declare types for Chart.PieceLabel.js.

Comment: I updated the answer - I have code that compiles just fine with your exact type definitions after installing all typings. Maybe it's something with JSX syntax, but I did not try it because I never use it myself

Comment: Again thanks for the help, but there still seems to be something else going on - looks like it's a problem in my app. An isolated test case (https://stackblitz.com/edit/zbj4nf) works fine, but in my app (https://git.io/vF23g) it still fails. I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Strange. I just cloned https://github.com/bayesimpact/tds-frontend, did `npm i`, I did not see your types in `node_modules/chart.piecelabel.js` so I copied `Chart.PieceLabel.d.ts` there and added `types` line to `package.json`, then removed `as any` from Doughnut options in `AdequacyDoughnut.tsx` and - it compiles! I see many other unrelated errors, but it seems to recognize `pieceLabel` in `options`.

Comment: What unrelated errors do you see? Repro steps are (1) clone the repo, (2) check out `personal/bcherny/publish-types` branch, (3) run `npm i`, (4) run `npm build`. Following these steps, I still see an error! You can also see it on CI here https://circleci.com/gh/bayesimpact/tds-frontend/122.

Comment: I'm seeing unrelated errors when I run `tsc` from command line, and it uses `tsconfig.json` from the root of `tds-frontend` (I had to remove `strict` from that tsconfig). The error in CI is from webpack, so probably there is something in `awesome-typescript-loader` config that makes typescript to behave differently compared to the command line.

Comment: Perhaps we're using different versions of `tsc`. Try running `./node_modules/.bin/tsc` - that gives just the one error.

Comment: We are using different versions of various typings - npm install is not reproducible unless you are using npm 5.0 and have `package-lock.json` checked in into the repo. I added my steps to the answer.

Comment: Oh man, JS is such a cluster. I'm actually using `yarn` (hence the yarn lockfile), not NPM. I was hoping that it would simplify the repro steps for people if I just said `npm`, but I guess not. It's also weird that CI gives the same error I see locally, but your NPM probably installs dependencies at a different set of versions. To fix the wabpack error you can run `touch .env`. Also I am out of town until Sunday, and will respond to you Sunday night.